# How do you say "as old as you are"? How to know when to use the correct as?

Tags: prepositions

I am a bit confused about which "as" to use in this sentence:
"as old as you are"

my attempt: "kiel maljuna lau estas vi"

I'd also like to know when you use each translation for the word as.

Answer (score 5):

I would translate this as:

> Tiel maljuna kiel vi estas

The words that start with *k* can be used to introduce a subphrase in the sentence. They usually refer back to a word in the sentence that starts *t*. For example the same thing happens with a phrase like:

> Tiu homo kiu lernis esperanton

So you can know which word to use to translate which *as* because the word before the subphrase is *kiel* and the one in the main part is *tiel*.

Comment: Good answer. Only thing I'd add is that in addition to *maljuna*, you could consider *aĝa* in this context. Context might matter to make that decision.